# _pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\x00'

Tags: python, machine-learning, pickle, random-forest, pre-trained-model

my code

```
def read_from_pickle():
    with open("RF.pkl",'rb') as file:
         clf = pickle.load(file)
         df = pd.read_csv("path")
        
         x_test = df.iloc[:, 0:48]
         y_test= df.iloc[:, -1]
         print(x_test)
        
         y_pred = clf.predict(x_test)
        
         score = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
    
         cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
         cm_list = cm.ravel()
         if (len(cm_list) > 1):
             tp, fn, fp, tn = cm_list

         else:
             tp = cm_list
             fn = 0
             fp = 0
             tn = 0

         print(cm_list)



with open("RF.pkl",'rb') as file:
         clf = pickle.load(file)
```

Error I'm receiving is

```
C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\Crispr_project\venv1\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:306: UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator DecisionTreeClassifier from version 0.20.2 when using version 0.21.3. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.
  UserWarning)
C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\Crispr_project\venv1\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\__init__.py:15: DeprecationWarning: sklearn.externals.joblib is deprecated in 0.21 and will be removed in 0.23. Please import this functionality directly from joblib, which can be installed with: pip install joblib. If this warning is raised when loading pickled models, you may need to re-serialize those models with scikit-learn 0.21+.
  warnings.warn(msg, category=DeprecationWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Dell/PycharmProjects/Crispr_project/load_RFpkl_model.py", line 68, in <module>
    clf = pickle.load(file)
_pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\x00'.
```

How to solve this error, I am trying to get the test accuracy from already trained model..
I have already tried re-downloading the file and try to run the code
And Changing the Decision tree classifier version
but nothing is working...
Can anyone please help

Comment: When did you create the pickle file? Did you do any changes in the code since you created the file? Are you sure the integrity of the file is OK?

Comment: @Chandini B C Did you find a solution?